# ImportError: cannot import name 'LlamaIndex' from 'llama_index'

Tags: python, importerror, llama, llama-index

while executing the following line of code in python

```
from llama_index import LlamaIndex
```

I am keep getting ImportError, how to rectify it.
Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'LlamaIndex' from 'llama_index'

I tried the code in both jupyter notebook and google colab, I can't rectify it
I am trying to execute following function

```
def remove_pii(text):

    llama = LlamaIndex()

    redacted_text = llama.redact(text)

    return redacted_text
```

I can't impoet LlamaIndex

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `from llama_index import LlamaIndex`, exactly what do you think this should mean, and **why** should it have this meaning? In particular, why should `LlamaIndex` be a meaningful thing that we could `import`, `from llama_index`? Where did you get the `llama_index` code from, and **what does the documentation say**, about how to use it?

Comment: I am trying to build a prompt where I am remove the PII data of user for that I get the code from open ai
"from llama_index import LlamaIndex
def remove_pii(text):
    
    llama = LlamaIndex()

    redacted_text = llama.redact(text)
    return redacted_text
text = "John Doe's phone number is 555-555-5555 and his email address is johndoe@example.com"
redacted_text = remove_pii(text)
print("Redacted Text: ", redacted_text)"
this is the code but while executing I am getting import error even after installing llama-index

Comment: That does not answer anything that I asked you, even slightly.

Comment: please check now

Comment: No, you miss the point completely. When you wrote `from llama_index import LlamaIndex`, **how did you decide** that it should say `LlamaIndex`, and not say anything else instead?

Comment: I don't know I am new to this field, I gave the task to chat gpt, It gave me the code I run it in jupyter notebook. In chat GPT the line of the code is from llama_index import LlamaIndex.

Comment: Please read that awesome manual.  Llama-index has proper documentation, you can start from there.

Comment: "I don't know I am new to this field" - then you should not be trying to get anywhere near the current problem. Please follow a tutorial from start to finish to learn Python fundamentals. And do not expect ChatGPT to teach you programming. It literally does not understand what it is saying.

Comment: sure @KarlKnechtel I do know python basic these libraries are new actually. I'll learn from scratch

Comment: sure @NikolajŠ. I will

Answer (score -2):

Did you install Llama index using PIP ??
if not then in cmd use:

```
pip install llama-index
```

Comment: yes I did install, but it doesn't work

Comment: This problem would give a different error message.